# react navigation : useIsFocused usage fails test cases

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I added the useIsFocused() to my file to accommodate focus event like

file.js

```
import { useIsFocused, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native"

const navigation = useNavigation()    
const isFocused = useIsFocused()

useEffect(() => {
  getData(somedata)
}, [isFocused])
```

But when i run my test file, the test fails

`TypeError: navigation.isFocused is not a function`

am I missing something here??

Comment: You can use this directly https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/